# Why does float argument fit to int function parameter?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion

Please, look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
  public:
    int my;
    A(int a=0) : my(a) { }
};

int main() {
  A x = 7; // 1
  A y = 6.7; // 2
  std::cout << x.my << " " << y.my << "\n";
}
```

It actually compiles although there is no `A(double a);` constructor. 
When exactly compiler is allowed to convert one argument type to another to call corresponding constructor?

Comment: `When exactly compiler is allowed to convert` Everytime [when an implicit conversion is possible and no better method].

Comment: [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) lists the standard conversions. Of particular interest here are floating-integral conversions.

Comment: Also, look up the difference between construction, `A x(7)` and assignment, `x = 7;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cppreference has [a list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) of standard conversions.  Of interest to you is the *Floating - integral conversions* section which can also be found in [N4140](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cplusplus/draft/master/papers/n4140.pdf) 4.9/1

> A prvalue of floating-point type can be converted to prvalue of any integer type. The fractional part is truncated, that is, the fractional part is discarded.

Finding `A(int)` to be callable with a standard conversion, the compiler inserts the necessary step to make the code work.  It's the same rule that allows `int x = 1.1` to compile

If this behavior is undesirable you can forbid it with an `=delete`

```
class A {
  public:
    //...
    A(int a);
    A(double) =delete;
};
```

Comment: What is the effect of `=delete`?

Comment: `A(int)` is called because it's the best match in the original code.  If there was an `A(double)` it would have called that instead. The `=delete` says that you don't want that function to be callable