# Using explicit constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

```
class foo {
public:
    explicit foo(int) { std::cout<<"int constructor"; }
}; 

int main() {
    foo f(0.1);
    return 0;
}
```

I thought explicit keyword was being used to prevent unwanted type conversions, but the above code still works and outputs "int constructor". Why? And how to prevent that in this case?

Comment: `main()` (with no return type) is a syntax error in C++.

Comment: My bad, will edit the post.

Comment: Surely this is a dupe? Edit: misunderstood.

Comment: `explicit` prevents a `foo` object from being implicitly created from an `int`, such as `f = 1;`.  That will compile without the `explicit` keyword on the `foo(int)` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing some concepts here.

`explicit` prevents *implicit constructor calls*, not *constructor calls with implicit parameter type conversions*.

Unfortunately the solution is not straightforward. It's not quite newbie-friendly and may require some googling to understand.

You *could* expicitly delete the constructors for floating-point types: `foo(float) = delete;` and so on. Then `foo f(0.1);` will cause 'use of deleted function' error. *But* you won't be able to do `foo f(1l)` either, the compiler will complain about 'ambiguous overloads'.

The proper way is following:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo(int) {std::cout << "int constructor\n";}
    template <typename T,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>
    foo(T) = delete;
};
```

It's similar to deleting overloads for each floating-point type (as described above), but due to SFINAE, the deleted overload won't be considered for non-floating-point types.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword `explicit` enforces a compile-time error with message as `conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘foo’ requested`, when you try to do an implicit conversion like this :`foo f = 1;`. That's all it's expected to do.

Why does it allow float value `0.1` is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957746/why-does-float-argument-fit-to-int-function-parameter).

Futhermore if you want to prevent this behavior, use this line of code:

```
foo(double) = delete;
```

then you would get an error: `use of deleted function ‘foo::foo(double)’` while passing a float/double value.

Answer (score 0):

An explicit constructor prevents implicit conversion into your type, from the type taken by the constructor. So in this case, it prevents implicit conversion from `int` into foo. So:

```
foo f = 1;
```

Will not compile. However, this is explicit construction:

```
foo f(1);
```

This, of course will work. In your case, you passed a double instead of an int. But there's an implicit conversion from double to int built into the language, that's why it compiles. In other words, your problem is that this compiles:

```
int x = 0.1;
```

However, compiling with `-Wconversion` on gcc (and I believe clang) will raise a warning for this, and if you are compiling with `-Werror` (which you should), it will turn this into a compilation error. I suspect MSVC has a similar error if you are working with that compiler.